# popoverPresentationController is nil when used with a Navigation View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This code was working properly before I embed my view in a navigation controller

```
if segue.identifier == "PopupInfo" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! PopoverInfoViewController
        controller.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = sender!.frame

    }
```

However, after adding the navigation controller, this slightly edited code is no longer working because popoverPresenetationController is now nil! I need to set its sourceRect programmatically not with the storyboard because the sender is a control inside a cell in a table view

```
if segue.identifier == "PopupInfo" {
        let navcontroller = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navcontroller.topViewController as! PopoverInfoViewController
        controller.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = sender!.frame

    }
```

Note: controller is not nil, only its popoverPresentationController property

Comment: Are you sure everything is properly connected in IB (assuming you’re using storyboards)?

Comment: Yes I am sure.. as soon as I commit the last line, everything works properly except for the position of the popover view

Comment: You embedded `PopoverInfoViewController` in a `UINavigationController`. That navigation controller is now being presented as a popover. It should now have a non-nil `popoverPresentationController` property, as it's the view controller that is directly embedded in the popover controller. Try `navcontroller.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = sender!.frame`

Comment: Thanks a lot @beyowulf please add an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You embedded `PopoverInfoViewController` in a `UINavigationController`. That navigation controller is what is directly embedded in a `UIPopoverPresentationController`. It should now have a non-nil `popoverPresentationController` property, as it's the view controller that is directly embedded in the popover controller. The setting of these kind of parent view controller properties do not propagate past the first child view controller. This is why `navcontroller.popoverPresentationController` will be non-nil while any child of navcontroller will have nil for `popoverPresentationController`.

You should use `navcontroller.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = sender!.frame`